# Tiny Flash Question

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I have this flash code - I need to add getURL(this.mainurl, "_self"); so that this.mainurl is a dynamic value from an XML file.

Can anybody maybe show me how to make the getURL value dynamic

myPhoto = new XML();

myPhoto.ignoreWhite = true;

myPhoto.onLoad = function(success) {

```
//portfolioTag = this.firstChild;

numimages = this.firstChild.childNodes.length;

spacing = 32;

for (i=0; i<numimages; i++) {
```

this.picHolder = this.firstChild.childNodes[i];

this.thumbHolder = thumbnails.createEmptyMovieClip("thumbnail"+i, i);

```
this.thumbHolder._x = i*spacing;

this.thumbLoader = this.thumbHolder.createEmptyMovieClip("thumbnail_image", 0);

this.thumbLoader.loadMovie(this.picHolder.attributes.thmb);

this.thumbHolder.mainurl = this.thumbHolder.attributes.mainurl;

this.thumbHolder.onRelease = function() {

    getURL(this.mainurl, "_self");
```

};

}

};

myPhoto.load("/flash/languages.xml");

XML FILE:

<
image title="Found" mainurl="http://www.de." thmb="\flash\image2.jpg"/>

Comment: You should reformat this so people will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

myPhoto = new XML();
myPhoto.ignoreWhite = true;
myPhoto.onLoad = function(success) {
    //portfolioTag = this.firstChild;
    numimages = this.firstChild.childNodes.length;
    spacing = 35;
    for (i=0; i